# <img> within mdl-card__supporting-text not properly shown

Tags: css, material-design-lite

I'm trying to use `<img>` within `mdl-card__supporting-text` but if the image is bigger than the card, the image would not scaled to fit within the card's supporting text area. See the [codepen](http://codepen.io/5amfung/pen/QEKPGE) for example.  See how the right side of the image is covered up.

I'm not expert in css and mdl.  I have also tried to search for a solution and didn't quite find one that would work.  If anyone has an idea, I would really appreciate if you could give a helping hand.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this simple snippet worked:

```
img {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

But if you will have more than just this image, you should consider using a class for this.

```
.card-img {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

And for better overview you should use the .mdl-card__media class on a div as the container, if you are trying to make a layout like this.

```
<div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp demo-card-square">
      <div class="mdl-card__media">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          Aenan convallis.
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
          <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
              View Updates
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Seriously, I have been pulling my hair out the whole day.  Thanks very much.